# Ruby on Rails - Controller Subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes, subdirectory

I am somewhat new to RoR,

I want to have a structured directory, because project may become big I don't want to have all controllers directly into `controllers` directory.

I would want something as

```
app/
    controllers/
          application_controller.rb
          groupa/
                athing_controller.rb
                athing2_controller.rb
          groupb/
                bthing_controller.rb
```

However when I place in the **routes.rb** the following:

```
get 'athing', :to => "groupa/athing#index"
```

I get the following error on **localhost:3000/athing/** :

> superclass mismatch for class AthingController

Which is like:

```
class AthingController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

Am I missing something?
Can I place subdirectories at all?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to use namespace instead:

In your routes:

```
namespace :groupa do
  get 'athing', :to => "athing#index"
end
```

In your controller:

```
class Groupa::AthingController < ApplicationController
```

In browser:

```
localhost:3000/groupa/athing/
```

Answer (score 4):

[**Modularity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design#Design_Concepts)

When you put your controllers (classes) into a subdirectory, Ruby/Rails expects it to [subclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html) from the parent (`module`):

```
#app/controllers/group_a/a_thing_controller.rb
class GroupA::AThingController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end

#config/routes.rb
get :a_thing, to: "group_a/a_thing#index" #-> url.com/a_thing
```

I've changed your model / dir names to conform to Ruby `snake_case` [convention](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-dirs):

> - Use `snake_case` for naming directories, e.g. `lib/hello_world/hello_world.rb`
> - Use `CamelCase` for classes and modules, e.g `class GroupA`

---

Rails routing has the [`namespace` directive](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) to help:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :group_a do
  resources :a_thing, only: :index #-> url.com/group_a/a_thing
end
```

... also the `module` directive:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :a_thing, only: :index, module: :group_a #-> url.com/a_thing
scope module: :group_a do
  resources :a_thing, only: :index #->  url.com/a_thing
end
```

The difference is that `namespace` creates a subdir in your *routes*, `module` just sends the path to the subdir-ed controller.

Both of the above require the `GroupA::` superclass on your subdirectory controllers.

Answer (score 3):

In config/routes.rb

```
namespace :namespace_name do
  resources : resource_name
end
```

In app/controllers/

create a module name with your namespace_name, in that place your controllers 
In that controller class name should be like
    class namespace_name::ExampleController < ApplicationController